# Movie about a couple straying into Alien Quarantine zone

Tags: story-identification

I remember seeing a movie a few (at least 3 or 4) years ago in the cinema. But I can't remember the name or the exact details, which makes it hard to search for online.

It was in a near future world where aliens were present on earth and quarantined into into areas. The movie focuses on a couple who enter the quarantine zone, I think to take pictures.

You don't see the aliens much, but I think they looked like metal Giant Octopus or Squid.
It was set in a jungle environment and I'm pretty sure it wasn't a big hollywood style movie, but shot on a lower budget.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This sounds to be [Monsters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monsters_(2010_film)), released in 2010.

It deals with a photojournalist trying to find a girl within a quarantined jungle. The jungle is full of aliens.

The film was very low budget, so aliens were rare sights. Their designs are very octopus-like.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You just beat me. I was writing my answer when I saw that you posted your answer and like 4 edits to it...

Comment: 100% correct answer, thanks!

Comment: Low budget or not, the aliens look pretty creative from your screenshots.

Comment: @Kzqai: They look similar to the Cthulhu-inspired aliens on *Babylon 5: Thirdspace*. Better though.

Comment: I asked the question because I remember the film being pretty awesome. Well worth a watch.

Comment: It is definitely worth watching.  The effects are good, considering the budget, but the main focus is on tension and character development.  I recall it being very well done.

Comment: From what I understand, the budget was largely spent on the effects. The low-budget really came into play in the actual filming, as they did everything very guerilla-style. Quick shots without permits and skeleton production crews.

Comment: As it turns out, there is a sequel slated for release Nov 2014. Monsters: Dark Continent.  The director (Gareth Edwards) is producing it but didn't direct, due to commitments with Godzilla.  He is also apparently slated to do a stand-alone Star Wars film.  I guess we'll see what happens.